# Drawing a square wave in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, draw, trigonometry

This python code illustrates a sin wave in a pygame window.

I want to draw a square wave in this very same fashion as well, though I have no idea what this code might be or how to draw a square wave / how one is constructed in python.

Does anybody know how I can do this? Is it possible with the same imports or will I need new ones?

Code:

```
    import sys, pygame, math
    from pygame.locals import *

    # set up a bunch of constants
    WHITE      = (255, 255, 255)
    DARKRED    = (128,   0,   0)
    RED        = (255,   0,   0)
    BLACK      = (  0,   0,   0)

    BGCOLOR = WHITE

    WINDOWWIDTH = 640 # width of the program's window, in pixels
    WINDOWHEIGHT = 480 # height in pixels
    WIN_CENTERX = int(WINDOWWIDTH / 2) # the midpoint for the width of the window
    WIN_CENTERY = int(WINDOWHEIGHT / 2) # the midpoint for the height of the window

    FPS = 160 # frames per second to run at

    AMPLITUDE = 80 # how many pixels tall the waves with rise/fall.

    # standard pygame setup code
    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Trig Waves')
    fontObj = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 16)

    # variables that track visibility modes
    showSine = True

    pause = False

    xPos = 0
    step = 0 # the current input f
    posRecord = {'sin': []} # keeps track of the ball positions for drawing the waves

    # making text Surface and Rect objects for various labels
    sinLabelSurf         = fontObj.render('sine', True, RED, BGCOLOR)

    sinLabelRect         = sinLabelSurf.get_rect()


    instructionsSurf = fontObj.render('Press Q to toggle wave. P to pause.', True, BLACK, BGCOLOR)
    instructionsRect = instructionsSurf.get_rect()
    instructionsRect.left = 10
    instructionsRect.bottom = WINDOWHEIGHT - 10

    # main application loop
    while True:
        # event handling loop for quit events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            # check for key presses that toggle pausing and wave visibility
            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_q:
                    showSine = not showSine
                elif event.key == K_p:
                    pause = not pause

        # fill the screen to draw from a blank state
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)

        # draw instructions
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(instructionsSurf, instructionsRect)



        # sine wave
        yPos = -1 * math.sin(step) * AMPLITUDE
        posRecord['sin'].append((int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY))
        if showSine:
            # draw the sine ball and label
            pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, RED, (int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY), 10)
            sinLabelRect.center = (int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY + 20)
            DISPLAYSURF.blit(sinLabelSurf, sinLabelRect)

        # draw the waves from the previously recorded ball positions
        if showSine:
            for x, y in posRecord['sin']:
                pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, DARKRED, (x, y), 4)


        # draw the border
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (0, 0, WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 1)

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

        if not pause:
            xPos += 0.5
            if xPos > WINDOWWIDTH:
                xPos = 0
                posRecord = {'sin': []}
                step = 0
            else:
                step += 0.008
                step %= 2 * math.pi
```

Python ver.2.6, Pygame ver.1.9.2

Comment: Someone use basic `sin()` to calculate position and draw dark red circle (one-by-one) without clearing screen. You will need some conditions to change light-red ball directions - to move it horizontally and vertically.

Comment: If you use `yPos = 0` in place of `yPos = -1 * math.sin(step) * AMPLITUDE` then you get horizontal line. Then you will have to change `yPos` from time to time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some modifications to add squared wave.

See places with `### HERE`.

```
import sys, pygame, math
from pygame.locals import *

# set up a bunch of constants
WHITE      = (255, 255, 255)
DARKRED    = (128,   0,   0)
RED        = (255,   0,   0)
BLACK      = (  0,   0,   0)
GREEN      = (  0, 255,   0) ### HERE
BLUE       = (  0,   0, 255) ### HERE

BGCOLOR = WHITE

WINDOWWIDTH = 640 # width of the program's window, in pixels
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480 # height in pixels
WIN_CENTERX = int(WINDOWWIDTH / 2) # the midpoint for the width of the window
WIN_CENTERY = int(WINDOWHEIGHT / 2) # the midpoint for the height of the window

FPS = 160 # frames per second to run at

AMPLITUDE = 80 # how many pixels tall the waves with rise/fall.

# standard pygame setup code
pygame.init()
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Trig Waves')
fontObj = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 16)

# variables that track visibility modes
showSine = True
showSquare = True ### HERE

pause = False

xPos = 0
step = 0 # the current input f

### HERE 
posRecord = {'sin': [], 'square': []} # keeps track of the ball positions for drawing the waves

# making text Surface and Rect objects for various labels

### HERE 
squareLabelSurf = fontObj.render('square', True, BLUE, BGCOLOR)
squareLabelRect = squareLabelSurf.get_rect()

sinLabelSurf = fontObj.render('sine', True, RED, BGCOLOR)
sinLabelRect = sinLabelSurf.get_rect()


instructionsSurf = fontObj.render('Press Q to toggle wave. P to pause.', True, BLACK, BGCOLOR)
instructionsRect = instructionsSurf.get_rect()
instructionsRect.left = 10
instructionsRect.bottom = WINDOWHEIGHT - 10

### HERE
yPosSquare = AMPLITUDE # starting position

# main application loop
while True:
    # event handling loop for quit events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        # check for key presses that toggle pausing and wave visibility
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_q:
                showSine = not showSine
            elif event.key == K_p:
                pause = not pause

    # fill the screen to draw from a blank state
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)

    # draw instructions
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(instructionsSurf, instructionsRect)

    # sine wave
    yPos = -1 * math.sin(step) * AMPLITUDE
    posRecord['sin'].append((int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY))
    if showSine:
        # draw the sine ball and label
        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, RED, (int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY), 10)
        sinLabelRect.center = (int(xPos), int(yPos) + WIN_CENTERY + 20)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(sinLabelSurf, sinLabelRect)

    # draw the waves from the previously recorded ball positions
    if showSine:
        for x, y in posRecord['sin']:
            pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, DARKRED, (x, y), 4)

    ### HERE - drawing horizontal lines
    # square 
    posRecord['square'].append((int(xPos), int(yPosSquare) + WIN_CENTERY))
    if showSquare:
        # draw the sine ball and label
        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, (int(xPos), int(yPosSquare) + WIN_CENTERY), 10)
        squareLabelRect.center = (int(xPos), int(yPosSquare) + WIN_CENTERY + 20)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(squareLabelSurf, squareLabelRect)

    # draw the waves from the previously recorded ball positions
    if showSquare:
        for x, y in posRecord['square']:
            pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, (x, y), 4)

    # draw the border
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (0, 0, WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 1)

    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

    if not pause:
        xPos += 0.5

        if xPos > WINDOWWIDTH:
            #sine ### HERE
            xPos = 0
            posRecord['sin'] = []
            step = 0

            # square ### HERE
            yPosSquare = AMPLITUDE
            posRecord['square'] = []
        else:
            #sine ### HERE
            step += 0.008
            #step %= 2 * math.pi

            # square ### HERE
            # jump top and bottom every 100 pixels
            if xPos % 100 == 0:
                yPosSquare *= -1
                # add vertical line
                for x in range(-AMPLITUDE, AMPLITUDE):
                    posRecord['square'].append((int(xPos), int(x) + WIN_CENTERY))
```

[image]

Comment: I add new code - now you can see label `square` below red ball. And I use `square` in variable names

Comment: I found one error when start drawing waves again - new code in answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, is there any way to make the ball move faster? Also, how can I make the wave begin already completed on the screen and just have the ball move along this pre-drawn line?

Comment: Script use variable `FPS` (Frames Per Second) to keep constant speed on faster and slower computers. You can change it to get faster move. Or you could draw more "dots" in one move (in one loop) - but this would need more changes in code.

Comment: I tried to change this, but it seems if FPS is any hgher, it reaches a limit at which it doesn't go any faster. how would the 'more dots in a loop' method work?